# Why does the Faraday effect happen in ferromagnets in particular?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, maxwell-equations

The [typical argument](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-04143-7_5) goes that light rotates because there's no reason that it wouldn't. More precisely,

1. magnetization defines an axis $\to$ the dielectric tensor *could* be different along that axis.
2. non isotropic dielectric tensor $\to$ light polarization rotates

(2) follows from Maxwells equation's, however I find (1) problematic.

(1) implies the purpose of the magnetization is just to make a "preferred axis". However, there are lots of other ways (e.g. non cubic latices) that seem more likely to affect the dielectric tensor.

So, why do commercial Faraday rotator's use magneto-optics, if we should be able to get the same dielectric tensor without magnets?
Why is it that there aren't other common rotators that don't use magnets?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but maybe it’s because an electro magnet can give a variable strength field at the turn of a dial.